Proving whether or not a markov chain is irreducible/recurrent? (Metropolis-within-Gibbs)
We want to generate samples from a standard normal distribution using a variation on slice sampling. To do this, the following Gibbs scheme is proposed to sample uniformly from the set $S = \{(u,x)\colon 0 < u < \phi(x)\}$:
Given $(U_0,X_0)\in A$ and $\delta > 0$,
\begin{align}
\text{for } i &= 1,2,\ldots, M\\
&U_i \sim \text{Unif}(0, \phi(X_{i-1})) \\
&\text{Sample }X_i \text{ with an MH-step targeting $f(x\,|\, U_{i}) \propto I(0 < u < \phi(x))$},\\ & \text{using proposal }\text{Unif}(X_{i-1}-\delta, X_{i-1}+\delta)
\end{align}
i.e. the step where we would sample from a vertical slice in the standard slice sampler has been replace with a Metropolis-Hastings step.
The question is to determine/prove whether the chain generated by this procedure is irreducible and recurrent.
My thoughts on the problem are that since the support of $\phi(\cdot)$ is connected, the chain should at least be irreducible, since we should be able to move to any point $(U^*, X^*)\in S$ in a finite number of steps by writing down an appropriate sequence of steps entirely within $S$ taken by the algorithm to get from an arbitrary starting point $(U_0, X_0)$ to our destination. Any idea on how to formalize this?
As for recurrence, I do not really know how to proceed.
